# Cisco IOS: Is ip inspect used?

Tags: firewall, cisco, router, ios

There is a Cisco IOS router with the following code in it. The below code seems to define *Context-based Access Control Engine* inspection rules. I don't think any of this is used.

The only occurences of the words `SDM_HIGH`, `DEFAULT100`, `inspect`, `appfw` are in the block of configuration that I am showing below.

Does this mean that these rules are not used? I would very much like to eliminate these from the configurations so that it can be smaller and easier to fully understand.

```
ip inspect log drop-pkt
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 appfw DEFAULT100
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 cuseeme
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 ftp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 h323
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 icmp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 netshow
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 rcmd
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 realaudio
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 rtsp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 esmtp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 sqlnet
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 streamworks
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 tftp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 tcp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 udp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 vdolive
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 bliff
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 imap
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 imaps
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 imap3
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 lotusnote
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 lotusmtap
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 pop3
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 pop3s
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 qmtp-tcp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 http
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 https
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 dns
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH appfw SDM_HIGH
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH icmp
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH dns
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH esmtp
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH imap reset
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH pop3 reset
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH tcp
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH udp
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH https
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH bliff
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH imaps
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH imap3
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH lotusnote
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH lotusmtap
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH pop3s
ip inspect name SDM_HIGH qmtp-tcp

....

appfw policy-name SDM_HIGH
  application im aol
    service default action reset alarm
    service text-chat action reset alarm
    server deny name login.oscar.aol.com
    server deny name toc.oscar.aol.com
    server deny name oam-d09a.blue.aol.com
    audit-trail on
  application im msn
    service default action reset alarm
    service text-chat action reset alarm
    server deny name messenger.hotmail.com
    server deny name gateway.messenger.hotmail.com
    server deny name webmessenger.msn.com
    audit-trail on
  application http
    port-misuse im action reset alarm
    port-misuse p2p action reset alarm
    port-misuse tunneling action reset alarm
    audit-trail on
  application im yahoo
    service default action reset alarm
    service text-chat action reset alarm
    server deny name scs.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name scsa.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name scsb.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name scsc.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name scsd.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name messenger.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs16.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs19.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs42.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs53.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs54.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name ads1.vip.scd.yahoo.com
    server deny name radio1.launch.vip.dal.yahoo.com
    server deny name in1.msg.vip.re2.yahoo.com
    server deny name data1.my.vip.sc5.yahoo.com
    server deny name address1.pim.vip.mud.yahoo.com
    server deny name edit.messenger.yahoo.com
    server deny name http.pager.yahoo.com
    server deny name privacy.yahoo.com
    server deny name csa.yahoo.com
    server deny name csb.yahoo.com
    server deny name csc.yahoo.com
    audit-trail on
!
appfw policy-name DEFAULT100
  application im aol
    service default action reset alarm
    service text-chat action reset alarm
    server deny name login.oscar.aol.com
    server deny name toc.oscar.aol.com
    server deny name oam-d09a.blue.aol.com
    audit-trail on
  application im msn
    service default action reset alarm
    service text-chat action reset alarm
    server deny name messenger.hotmail.com
    server deny name gateway.messenger.hotmail.com
    server deny name webmessenger.msn.com
    audit-trail on
  application http
    strict-http action reset alarm
    port-misuse im action reset alarm
    port-misuse tunneling action reset alarm
    audit-trail on
  application im yahoo
    service default action reset alarm
    service text-chat action reset alarm
    server deny name scs.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name scsa.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name scsb.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name scsc.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name scsd.msg.yahoo.com
    server deny name messenger.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs16.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs19.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs42.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs53.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name cs54.msg.dcn.yahoo.com
    server deny name ads1.vip.scd.yahoo.com
    server deny name radio1.launch.vip.dal.yahoo.com
    server deny name in1.msg.vip.re2.yahoo.com
    server deny name data1.my.vip.sc5.yahoo.com
    server deny name address1.pim.vip.mud.yahoo.com
    server deny name edit.messenger.yahoo.com
    server deny name http.pager.yahoo.com
    server deny name privacy.yahoo.com
    server deny name csa.yahoo.com
    server deny name csb.yahoo.com
    server deny name csc.yahoo.com
    audit-trail on
!
!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your configuration, these rules are **NOT** in use.  Carefully check each router interface for evidence of an "ip inspect" command to be sure (show run | in inspect).  If they were enabled, I would expect to see (for example):

```
interface serial 0/0
 ip inspect SDM_HIGH in
 ip inspect DEFAULT100 in
```

The document below may be helpful to explain exactly what you are seeing and provides examples of how these commands are tied together:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_4t/12_4t4/ht_fw_im.html